# ReportViewer, Index outside the bounds of array (RDLC report) C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, report, rdlc

I am trying to generate a rdlc report, and right now dataSet is throwing an exception. i.e "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

In command view, I get following error in command window.

```
>? dataTable.GetErrors()[0]

   'dataTable.GetErrors()[0]' threw an exception of type 
   'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146233080
HelpLink: null
IPForWatsonBuckets: {0}
InnerException: null
IsTransient: false
Message: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
RemoteStackTrace: null
Source: null
StackTrace: null
TargetSite: null
WatsonBuckets: null
_HResult: -2146233080
_className: null
_data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
_dynamicMethods: null
_exceptionMethod: null
_exceptionMethodString: null
_helpURL: null
_innerException: null
_ipForWatsonBuckets: {0}
_message: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
_remoteStackIndex: 0
_remoteStackTraceString: null
_safeSerializationManager: {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager}
_source: null
_stackTrace: null
_stackTraceString: null
_watsonBuckets: null
_xcode: -532462766
_xptrs: {0}
```

on historical debugging, it points toward these codes

```
public virtual int Fill(ReportDataSet.DataTable1DataTable dataTable)
{
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
    if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true))
    {
        dataTable.Clear();
    }

    int returnValue = Adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Report viewer remains blank. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As the maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216. So if your result has more than this records you will get "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error.

Comment: It's much, much more likely to be with the columns, but good try anyway

Comment: I am retrieving records from 9-11 columns only, so currently I have only 1 record to retrieve i.e 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error was legit.
It was my fault. particular column only belonged to a specific type of customer. However I was pulling all records, hence the length was declared e.g 3,  but then because of that column it used to become 4,

anyways, I generated two reports,  and now everything is fine.
Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

Avoid expression in RDLC report files

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.